# How to receive a CallbackQuery in a Telegram BOT

Tags: telegram-bot

I want to use [InlineKeyboardButton](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardbutton) in a telegram bot.

My request is a GET request to the following url<sup>1</sup>

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot{TOKEN}/sendMessage?chat_id={ID}&text=Hello&reply_markup={"inline_keyboard":[[{"text":"Click","callback_data":"1"}]]}
```

I receive the message with one inline button and it works as expected however, after clicking the button there are no updates received.

I've read the documentation many times and I would excpect an update with `callback_query` field but none is received.

I created another bot, and it works exactly as expected. So now the question is

- Why would the old bot fail to work as expected? it's a very old bot, created very long ago, does that have anything to do?

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Of course, with the correct bot token and chat id.</sub>

Comment: how do you send this `HTTP` request?

Comment: I did in many ways *curl* from the command line, from a python program using *urllib*. Why do you ask?

Comment: i tried it using curl and it works as expected - I can get update with `CallbackData`. How do you get updates btw?

Comment: The same way, by issuing a GET request with `getUpdates` method.

Comment: @IvanVinogradov I pass no parameters to it, is there anything special I don't know?

Comment: you should be using `offset` and `timeout` parameters of `getUpdates`, but for testing purposes it's okay to use no additional parameters at all. I use curl like that: `curl -v https://api.telegram.org/bot{BOT}:{TOKEN}/sendMessage?chat_id={CHAT_ID}&text=Hello`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I cannot reproduce this issue with my bot.

However, the following issues *may* cause problem described in your question:

- bot API keys of `sendMessage` and `getUpdates` methods are different
- `offset` parameter of `getUpdates` method might be invalid, causing needed updates to be [confirmed](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getupdates) and never 
  returned to you by telegram servers
- there might be a different
  app running `getUpdates` preventing you from receiving needed updates